# Why would you want to store an empty string instead of null?

Tags: php, string, null, is-empty

Is there any case for using an empty string instead of `null`? I'm looking for any domain or business context where you would want to use the empty string instead of using `null`

I'm pondering this in terms of the HTTP stack, for example in php a request with a query string that looks like https://example.com/something?key= would be interpreted as an empty string.

```
var_dump($_GET['key']);
```

> string(0) ""

And for every use case my limited imagination can conceive, this should always be converted to `null` so why would anyone have a need to store `""` in a database field or something like that?

Comment: That must have been the question Oracle asked themselves when defining their DBMS ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of empty strings instead of null - a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723242/use-of-empty-strings-instead-of-null-a-good-practice)

Comment: You can see it as if a column has `null`, it haven't been set at all, while if it contains a string, then it has been set but without any content. That way, you can, for example, see if a field has been updated or if it still has the original value (null). That's just one use case. There are plenty more.

Comment: One scenario I could see is if you have a model, and lazy load the data when you need it, you could have `isset($name) ? $name : $model->load('name')` which to avoid reloading it multiple times if it had already been loaded and was just empty it would have to be `string(0) ""` rather than `NULL`. (caching would be the primary scenario where I actually see this happening)

Answer (score 3):

The concept of `NULL` is used to represent a value that is not known. This is easier to grasp in the database context, where an entire row is inserted in the database at a time. The fields whose values are not known are initialized with `NULL`.

The programming languages that support the concept usually use `NULL` as the value of the uninitialized variables. This usage shifts the general perception of `NULL` towards the idea of *"not set"*. In fact, the semantics of `NULL` in this context is also *"unknown"*.

An empty string (`''`) is a different thing. It represents the absence of any character in a string. It doesn't mean the value (of type string) is not known; it is known: it is empty. Using it instead of `NULL` is a logic error.

In the context of the HTTP `GET` request whose URL is `https://example.com/something?key=`, processed by a PHP script, `$_GET['key']` is `''` (the empty string). The value is known, the `key` variable is present in the URL and its value is the empty string. But `$_GET['foo']` is correctly evaluated by PHP as `NULL`. The value is simply not known. It is not the empty string; it can be any value but since it was not sent in the URL we cannot know it.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This is a nice answer, but I'm afraid it's to a different question. You provided a good definitive explanation, but I was looking for a real world example of when you would want to store an empty string instead of `null`

Comment: I think that a correct design never uses an empty string instead of `null` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

As the database is concerned, an empty string and a NULL values are two different things. You can tell them apart and query each other specifically. As a weakly typed language, PHP tends to blur the line, but that doesn't mean it is the case everywhere in the software ecosystem.

On the other hand, one of the primary uses of php is to handle http form values, which are all of type string by nature. Maybe that doesn't help either.

Comment: `null` and an empty string `""` are two different things in PHP as well. And _"one of the primary uses of php is to handle http form values"_ - I must have missed that memo.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware that they are different things. My question is why would you ever want to use an empty string in any domain/business context?

Comment: Example of why you might have the difference ... null, no value provided; empty string, value is nothing.... e.g. "what is your middle name?": "I'm not going to tell you", null; "I don't have a middle name", empty string

Comment: @JeffPuckett in some cases you have to deal with types in php, which is not easy to do, that's why operators such as `===` exist. In such cases you want to tell them apart. Unit tests are one example of such cases.

Comment: @Calimero yes, as I said, I am fully aware that `null !== ""`

Comment: @JeffPuckett I take it you don't write unit tests, do you ? that's one case where you typically want type-level acuracy. In that respect, you cannot have too many different data types to compare with.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson replying to your first comment : I'm not saying they are the same, but PHP is opinionated to blur the boundary on purpose, silently converting them to one another depending on usage. Ever heard of Personal Home Page ?

Comment: PHP has evolved quite a bit since it first came out in it's first form in 1994 (when it got it's name). Today it's way beyond the simple templating language it once_was. I use PHP everyday at work (and so do many of my friends) and _"handle http form values"_ is definitely not the major part of what we're doing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson slightly off topic there but some core things haven't changed much since those days, e.g. type juggling and superglobals. Yes today you can do a billion amazing other things with it than http handling, that doesn't change what it is initially meant to be used for. And it's still widely used for that simple case, just looking at other questions.